# Is there a no-code way to add a widget to a website that does not require changing the website's code base?

Tags: html, web, widget, mobile-website

Is there a way to add a widget to a website (e.g. a small button that hovers in the corner that you can click to be redirected to another site) without having to add a code snippet like e.g. intercom requires?

Context: looking at a user base for a service that all don't know how to code or change their website code base, but would benefit tremendously from a widget on their website.

Thanks!

Comment: Recommend if someone who doesnt know how to code needs to maintain a website they use something like Wordpress or Wix or other website builder.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using WordPress for your site-building? widget is a very very simple thing to add-on it without doing any coding... All the designing matters on which tool you are building your site...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find a code script on the internet, however if you still feels that you can't add it successfully to your website, you can always find online freelancers to do it for you on very minimal prices correctly.